# HOW To Get Product Info Using REST API In Magento

Tags: rest, api, magento, oauth, product

How To Create **REST** **API** And How To Fetch The Magento **Products Info**..

Is there any demo available for above?

Answer (score 1):

**Products Specific Magento REST API Requests**
Retrieve the list of products, create, update, or delete a product. You will call Magento REST API like this:
[http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest/products](http://Products%20Specific%20Magento%20REST%20API%20Requests)

**Product Categories**
Retrieve the list of categories assigned to the product, assign, and unassign the category to/from the specific product. You will call Magento REST API like this:
http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest/products/:productId/categories

**Product Images**
Retrieve the list of images assigned to the product, add, update, and remove an image to/from the specific product. You will call Magento REST API like this:
http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest/products/:productId/images

**Magento REST API examples:**

```
$callbackUrl = "http://www.my-magento-store.com/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://www.my-magento-store.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://www.my-magento-store.com/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://www.my-magento-store.com/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '{Consumer Key}';
$consumerSecret = '{Consumer Secret}';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'My Product Name',
            'description'       => 'My Product Description',
            'short_description' => 'My Products Short Description',
            'price'             => 6.99,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

As you can see in the code given above, at the top you have to declare your connection, authetication tokens. Since this example is using oAuth authentication you need to specify it’s location on your host, consumer and secret key before you make a call to http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest/. If everything is alright you can create a JSON array of your simple product ready to push live.

**Now, let’s look at another example**

```
$callbackUrl = "http://www.my-magento-store.com/oauth_customer.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://www.my-magento-store.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://www.my-magento-store.com/oauth/authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://www.my-magento-store.com/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest';
$consumerKey = '{Consumer Key}';
$consumerSecret = '{Consumer Secret}';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

The above code will retrieve the list of all products as a customer via Magento REST API. Keep in mind that authorization headers are required for Admin and Customer user types. If you are enabling REST for guests you can do like this:
http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest/products?limit=1

**This will result in the following XML output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <magento_api>
      <data_item>
        <entity_id>18</entity_id>
        <type_id>simple</type_id>
        <sku>SKU Number</sku>
        <description>Your Product Description
    </description>
        <meta_keyword>Meta Keywords </meta_keyword>
        <short_description>Short Description</short_description>
        <name>Product Name</name>
        <meta_title>Product Title</meta_title>
        <meta_description>Meta Desciption</meta_description>
        <regular_price_with_tax>Regular Price of the product </regular_price_with_tax>
        <regular_price_without_tax>Price without Tax</regular_price_without_tax>
        <final_price_with_tax>Final Price With Tax</final_price_with_tax>
        <final_price_without_tax>Final Price without Tax</final_price_without_tax>
        <is_saleable>1</is_saleable>
        <image_url>Path of the product image</image_url>
      </data_item>
  </magento_api>
```

Similarly, you can call REST API URL’s to get specific XML data with limit parameter, default is 10 products per request but one request can only request a maximum of 100 products. To get the next set of results call like this:
http://www.my-magento-store.com/api/rest/products?page=2&limit=10

I hope this is enough to get started with Magento REST API.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below for get product detail, here `:productId` dynamic variable so you have to just pass **product ID** or you can also pass **SKU**

`GET http://magentohost/api/rest/products/:productId`